# How do I transfer meeting ownership in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

My secretary is leaving and we have a lot of meetings she has set up. How do I transfer ownership of these meeting?

If I cannot do this the new temp will have to input all the meetings again from her login and we will have to do it again when permanent staff are in place.

Answer (score 19):

That functionality is not possible with Outlook to date. The original organizer must cancel the meeting and new organizer create a new one. If the meeting is on a shared calendar, an admin can remove it, but not change the owner. That is the only way.

> Outlook does not provide a way to change a meeting organizer. To
>   change the meeting organizer of a recurring meeting, end the recurring
>   meeting. To do this, set an earlier end date and send the update to
>   all attendees. After you complete this step, the new organizer should
>   create a new recurring meeting.

[Source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/best-practices-when-using-the-outlook-calendar-HA104004449.aspx)

[Additional info](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/bd0408b9-a49b-476b-abfa-b1e1f44ce66a/in-outlook-2010-can-you-change-the-meeting-organizer?forum=exchangesvrclientslegacy)

Answer (score 7):

It is not possible, but here is a workaround

1. Open the original message
2. Reply to all
3. Save the message (it will be saved in your draft folder)
4. Click (don't open) the message in your draft folder
5. Click "Meeting" in the respond section of the outlook ribbon

Comment: This does not actually change the owner of the meeting. Rather, it is a convenient solution for the new organizer to easily create a duplicate meeting; though they will still have to manually set the date, time, and recurrence pattern. Basically, instead of leading with "It is possible", you should lead with "It is not possible, but here is a workaround".

Comment: Here's an explanation with screens and video: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/4401-outlook-change-meeting-organizer-owner.html

Answer (score 1):

If you secretary needs to do this the she is the owner and organizer of the meeting. You are just a participant. If the person leaves then her account should be disabled or deleted and you loose the meetings. Sadly that is just the way it is.

What you might want to do is either:

- Look into the functionality of delegates and let your secretary arrange things *on your behalf*
- or create a functional account rather than a personal account.

Functional accounts are things like 'management@place.tld', not "jane@.." or "Joe@..".

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with this issue myself, I found a workable solution!

- First, share the calendar with the appropriate staff person (the new owner).
- Then go to calendars and right click on the specific
  calendar.
- Select Properties.
- Click on Permissions.
- Scroll to find the name of the staff member you are transferring the calendar to.
- Click on the name of the person.
- Change their permissions to **Owner** and check off all appropriate boxes.
- Click Apply!

I hope this information is helpful to you.
All my best! Colleen

Comment: I don't see any `Properties` option when I right click on a calendar entry.

Comment: @William Works, if you actually share the calender. Properties are available in the left sidebar: My calenders. I tested it in MS Office Professional Plus 2013.

Comment: @Stefan. Nope. This let's you transfer the entire Calendar. It does not let you transfer individual Calendar entries (ie meetings).

Comment: This is transferring a whole calendar, NOT a meeting, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Something I found that helps is emailing the calendar to the new owner.  Just right click on the calendar, email (make sure it emails as an attachment), then select who it's going to.  The new owner will open up the calendar and save it, it will save under "Other Calendars", but they can move it to "Shared" or "Personal".  The new owner will have their own version created (thus making them the admin of that calendar) and can share and continue working with it from there.  So far we have not had problems with this process.  Hope this helps!

**EDIT**
By the way, I would only do this with one person and let them share it.  When you email it, it will not sync with the original copy, only shared calendars do that.

Answer (score 0):

Export your calendar to a csv file and then reimport it, replacing the duplicates with the imported entries.
Alternatively, give the exported file to the temp and have them import it into their calendar.
Caveat: review the imported calendar entries with the entries in the csv file to ensure that all of the attendees are listed in the Scheduling Assistant.