# How to set yourself as "Not Attending" for an instance of a recurring meeting you've Organized?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, meeting-request

I'm the "Organizer" of a recurring daily meeting (our daily stand up). **I want to set *my own* status to "Not attending" *for a specific instance* and if possible (bonus) even remove that instance from my own calendar.** I want to keep the recurring appointment itself, as I don't want to loose any instance changes I've made.

What I've tried (in addition to SU and Google searches) to find out how to do is are the basics obviously. First, I've meticulously gone through the relevant window:

[image: Outlook meeting window]

However, none of the buttons seems to do what I want. I'm expecting something similar to this piece of ribbon I have for meetings organized by others:

[image: response options]

Or, I'd also perhaps expect I could (right) click on my name or the icon in front of it.

Finally, as per the suggestions in the comments, I've looked to see if I could change the organizer of the specific instance so I could "decline" the meeting or have myself removed, but it [seems you can't change the meeting organizer](https://superuser.com/q/727471/82470).

Perhaps this is just not possible? Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: Can you set other people as owner/organizer of the meeting (and then delete yourself)? I don't think you can remove yourself if you are the only organizer.

Comment: @Darius Thanks for the suggestion. It *seems* [you can't *change* the meeting organizer](http://superuser.com/q/727471/82470) (at least I don't see any option for it). In any case, you did alert me I should update my question to specify it's about an instance of a *recurring* meeting (which may complicate things).

Comment: You can make a separate Calendar and put your recurring meeting there to at least "hide" from your view.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Meeting organizer is required to attend by default.

If you have an iPhone with iOS 7 or iOS 8, you can try to exploit a bug to make the [meeting organizer optional](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2563324).

Comment: Well, unfortunately your answer (i.e. "not possible") seems to be it. :'|

Answer (score 7):

Potential Workaround:

If your concern is to keep your calendar free during that time slot, you can set the "Show As" to "Free" on the meeting stub and your calendar will appear free during that time slot.

Comment: Do you know whether this "Show As" will affect other users of the event?

Answer (score -1):

Go in your calendar, right click on the recurrent meeting, select delete, evenet-do not send a response

Comment: Thx for the response. However, if I delete an event I'm organizing, it will _cancel_ it for all users, non?

Comment: @RoxanaPopa - `evenet` or `event`?